# Show events date instead of article date in default calendar widget

Tags: events, calendar

I need to use the default calendar widgets, but instead to highlight the article's date, I would show the events date

What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to WP.SE. What exactly are "events"? A taxonomy term? A post type post? Where does it come from (shown in code)? Please (always) answer with an [edit] to your question. Also make sure to read [ask] to attract the best possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I don't think you can modify the Calendar Widget at least not that easy as like passing a post type and a field to query for.

You have a few options:

- Create a Widget.
- Create a function like `get_calendar()` on line 1.406 on general-template.php file (wp 4) and pass it via `get_calendar` filter.
- Install a plugin that offers an event post type with a calendar widget.

ps: don't modify general-template.php is a bad practice and when wordpress gets updated you will loose all your modifications.

Read more about it:

- [Using a different wordpress function instead of the default one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569422/using-a-different-wordpress-function-instead-of-the-default-one)
- [Modify Native Calendar Widget for Event Post Types](http://shout.setfive.com/2013/07/25/wordpress-modify-native-calendar-widget-for-event-post-types/)

If you have PHP and MySQL skills this should give you a starting point in how to solve this.

Sorry for bad english.